# Keras, custom image dataset, binary result with percentage

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, keras

I have this two big groups of images. Every image has a percentage attached to it. I have a model trained with those images that returns a binary result, either 0 or 1. I want to return a percentage of how sure is the machine about the 0 or the 1.

For sake of an example, let's say they are Cat images. I have also a percentage on how big the 'cat' is (100% is very big, 0% is very small). I want that the model tells me "This is a cat 78% big".

My current dataset is based on two folders (big cats and small cats). The first number is the number of the image (1 to 1000, for example). The second number is the percentage of how big the cat is:

```
../big_cats
    cat1_78.png
    cat2_97.png
    cat3_67.png
    ...
../small_cats
    cat1_12.png
    cat2_9.png
    cat3_24.png
    ...
```

So right now I don't use the percentage, I either get a 0 or 1 (either big or small), but my objective would be that the model uses it to tell me "This is a 67% big cat", where 50% would be medium cat, 100% the biggest cat, 0% the smallest cat.

I have tried using `softmax` and `categorical_cassentropy`, but this just tells the estimated accuracy of the binary decision where the cat is big or small (if I understood correctly).

My question is: How can I prepare the dataset to get that result? How to create the data train and validation to read this percentage in the image name? Is there any tutorial I can follow? I need to use `Keras + Tensorflow`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a Dense (1) or (2) and **softmax** function for the output prediction layer because you want to know whether the picture is a cat or not a cat (two classes). That means you need to reshape your label to (num_pic, 2) where the first column is to indicate if the picture is a cat, and the second column is to indicate if the picture is not a cat; or (num_pic, 1) to just indicate whether it is a cat or not.

This way, each of the two (or one) output neuron will be a number between 0 and 1, which can be used as a probability.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I am using now `softmax` and `categorical_cassentropy`:

`x = Dense(2, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)
    my_model = Model(input=input, output=x)
    my_model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])`

Going to give an update once I finish training the model and getting some valuable feedback. Again, thank you.

Comment: Hello @yilun-zhang, from my understanding your answer is right in a way, but for my application is not the right one. How can I make predictions based on qualities from the same class? Not if it's a cat or not, but how big the cat is, where 100% is very big and 0% is very small, and I have 10,000 photos of cats of every percentage? Sorry if my question wasn't clear enough, it has helped me already understanding a lot of things.

Comment: @aramusss In that case, it's a totally different machine learning problem. For this one, you will need correct label (the size of the cat in the image) to train a sort of regression model in order to predict the size of the cat. It's not a classification problem any more.

Comment: I've updated the issue I hope with much clearer example. Yes, you are right, doesn't look like a classification issue anymore. Could you tell me what to search, or any example of someone doing something similar? I couldn't find any in my research. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @aramusss Basically, in order to treat it as a regression problem, you need to change the softmax function and the loss function. You can search for "keras regression" and there are some examples that you can follow to get some understanding on the task.